# ReadProcessMemory failed with error code 299 (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY)

Tags: c++, winapi, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to make a simple debugger as my homework.
The debugger does 3 steps.

1. Read a exe file with `rb` flag, get its EntryPoint.
2. Call `CreateProcess` with flag `CREATE_SUSPENDED | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS`, then set a breakpoint at EntryPoint
3. When debugee was stopped at EntryPoint. Read codes from EntryPoint.

Now my problem is, `CreateProcess` returns true, but the following `ReadProcessMemory` returns false and `GetLastError` returns 299, AKA `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`, so I can't set breakpoint at EntryPoint. I've search on Stack Overflow with keywords `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` and `ReadProcessMemory` and read some questions and answers, but those answers cannot solve my problem.

My approach comes here: [Syringe](https://github.com/Ares-Developers/Syringe/blob/master/SyringeDebugger.cpp), it is a 32-bit program, which runs well on my 64-bit PC.

Environment:

- Windows 10 20H2 (19042), 64-bit.
- CMake(generated by Visual Studio 2019, I didn't specify anything except linking zydis) generator: Visual Studio 2019,  compiler: MSVC v142.
- Compiled with x86-debug mode

Here is my code snippet

```cpp
    auto* file = fopen("../debugee.exe", "rb");
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHdr;
    fread(&dosHdr, sizeof IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, 1, file);
    fseek(file, dosHdr.e_lfanew, SEEK_SET);

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders;
    fread(&ntHeaders, sizeof IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, 1, file);
    auto IsWin32 = ntHeaders.OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC;
    std::cout << "parsing " << (IsWin32 ? "PE32" : "PE64") << " file\n";

    auto imageBase = ntHeaders.OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
    auto entry = ntHeaders.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint + imageBase;
    auto codeSize = ntHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfCode;

    STARTUPINFO startupInfo{sizeof STARTUPINFO};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    auto r = CreateProcess(
        "../debugee.exe", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, false,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS,
        nullptr, nullptr, &startupInfo, &pInfo);
    printf("create process: %s, handle: %p\n", r ? "success" : "fail", pInfo.hProcess);

    char buffer = 0;
    char INT3 = 0xCC;
    printf("address of buffer: %p\n", &buffer);
    r = ReadProcessMemory(pInfo.hProcess, reinterpret_cast<void*>(entry), &buffer, 1, nullptr);

    auto err = GetLastError();
    printf("read: %s, error: %08X\n", r ? "success" : "fail", err);
    r = WriteProcessMemory(pInfo.hProcess, reinterpret_cast<void*>(entry), &INT3, 1, nullptr);
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("patch: %s, error: %08X\n\n", r ? "success" : "fail", err);
    ResumeThread(pInfo.hThread);
```

The output is

```
parsing PE32 file
create process: success, handle: 00000100
address of buffer: 00D3F5CF
read: fail, error: 0000012B
patch: fail, error: 000003E6 // WriteProcessMemory got another error ERROR_NOACCESS, I don't know if there are corelation, but I want to figure out why I got ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY first
```

Comment: module can load not at *ntHeaders.OptionalHeader.ImageBase* - so this is your main error.

Comment: [`ImageBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32) is *"the **preferred** address of the first byte of the image when it is loaded in memory"*. That's a request only, and the OS loader is free to ignore or override it.

Comment: Yes, but that is what Syringe does,  Syringe runs well on my PC.  And OS usually load exe at ImageBase, doesn't it?

Comment: Because Syringe is a debugger, it just read ImageBase and AddressOfEntryPoint from a exe, and set a breakpoint at entry point(the code is `setBP(ImageBase + AddressOfEntryPoint)`). This program runs on at least 10 thousand PCs. So I don't think it is wrong.  `CREATE_SUSPENDED`  make the subprocess suspended before it runs to the entry point,

Comment: `CreateProcess` returns TRUE, and the following Win32 API is `ReadProcessMemory`

Comment: what you still want ? answer already exist - *ntHeaders.OptionalHeader.ImageBase* - not correct use. use `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO::lpBaseOfImage`

Comment: I'm trying the new approach. I just wonder why the same code got error on my PC.